# Add another domain to mailcow for send/receive mails

Tags: email, dns

I have some trouble in adding another domain to mailcow, i did all configs (MX, DKIM, SPF .. etc) i can send mails but i cant recieve in the inbox, i think there is somthing wrong.

here is my config :

i have mail.domain.com configured properly
then i create a domain2.com and added it to mailcow “add domain” and got the dkim key
in the domain provider i made this setup

```
SPF : “v=spf1 ip4:<server-ip> all”
DKIM: dkim._domainkey with the value from mailcow UI
autoconfig CNAME points to mail.domain.com
autodiscover CNAME points to mail.domain.com
domain2.com MX 10 mail.domain.com
```

I can send emails with the new domain but i cant recieve

Comment: Can you receive Email now?

Answer (score 1):

This is for single mail server that uses multiple domains. That implies that the IP is the same for all domains, because they run from the same server.

If you use different IPs for each domain, then you can use the `v=spf1 mx a -all` flag.